# Dropbox not working in fresh Freya 0.3.1 installation

Tags: applications

I currently reinstalled Freya 0.3.1 on my notebook as I still have been using the beta. Now, I can't get Dropbox to work again (was working fine before). I tried downloading the .deb file from the website and install it with dpkg as well as adding the dropbox repository manually and installing dropbox using apt-get.

Doesn't matter how I install it, when I start dropbox with `dropbox start -i` I get a `Aborted (core dumped)`. Anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Following the steps of this [link](http://www.cyberfella.co.uk/2015/06/26/installing-dropbox-on-elementaryos-freya/) worked for me.

Good luck!

Simon

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Would be nice to have such a script in the elementary ppas =)